# Benchmarking Tool for Java/Web Apps

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, benchmarking

I am trying to find a tool to basically be able to give a statsD(https://github.com/etsy/statsd) deamon running in my environment, database and method execution times.

Is there a way I can plug into JDBC and the classes, and send out the times for each of the sql queries along with the query. I also need to profile each of the methods, and the stack trace, and be able to measure the time taken by each method to complete.

Ideally it'd be really nice if we could just package this as a JAR, and the developer can pretty much use it in Plug N Play mode.

Thanks;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are deployed on tomcat: [Spring Insight](http://www.springsource.org/insight) (stand alone WAR) will do all the work for you, including SQL queries. If you are using Spring Tool Suite, it'd even jump directly to the code from where "this" query was fired.

[image]

Comment: Or you can download their memorably-named _"vFabric tc Server Developer Edition with Spring Insight"_

Comment: yep, if the name does not scare you :)

Comment: If I am not using Spring, but using Insight on Tomcat, will it be able to drill down to the level of line by line code?

Comment: theoretically it should ( "byte code" is "byte code" ), but practically I am using Spring for JVM coding mostly => you have to try it.